# Need help converting cURL to PHP

Tags: php, curl

Im kind of new to php, and have never used cURL. But i am currently working on a project that uses another service that is required for my project. And i need some helt converting a cURL line that was given by the other service provider and works as it should trough the terminal to php.

The cURL line is

```
curl -u 'myusername:myApiKey' -F 'userId=39282' https://example.com/api
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can use `exec()` http://php.net/function.exec to run commands from the terminal through a PHP script

Comment: i need help converting my unpainted house to painted

Comment: Seriously? First Google Result for [php curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Okay, i'll try exec. But i thought that it only worked on linux servers. My webserver is running on windows server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something similar?

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://myusername:myApiKey@example.com/api");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('userId' => '39282')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, let's see.  You're sending form data to `https://example.com/api`, that requires a username and password to login.

You can do it like this:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://example.com/api');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'myusername:myApiKey',
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'userId' => 39282
    ),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Check the docs for all cURL options: http://php.net/curl_setopt